# How to explain the upcoming Root Certificate Expiration period without technical terms?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

A lot of users on older devices or IoT devices that don't or can't get updates will encounter problems in the coming year or two because a lot of the original long-lasting CA root certificates will expire.

Because this is a very technical problem that most people will be totally unaware of and probably won't understand if someone will explain it to them using technical terms, there is a need for an explanation (or maybe multiple) that can be understood by non-technical users so that if they're one of those users on an older device, at the very least they know what's going on.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a problem to solve. "Your security will break without an update." Why is there a need to explain why? People are used to needing to apply security updates ... "You need to update your encryption certificates" would seem to work just as well if people desire more detail.

Answer (score 5):

> .... there is a need for an explanation (or maybe multiple) that can be understood by non-technical users so that if they're one of those users on an older device, at the very least they know what's going on.

The technical reason is irrelevant for these users. All they want to know is the effect (for example device no longer works, exact behavior depends on the exact device) and who to blame for.

The blamable problem here is not the Root Certificate Expiration since this was a foreseeable problem which could have been addressed by the vendor: if the device is able to get to the internet it should be able to get updates with the new root CA too. Instead the vendor of the device is to blame in that he either did not foresee the problem and introduced the necessary steps to deal with it or that he explicitly decided to ignore the problem.

The sufficient explanation is therefore: the device does not (fully) work any more because the vendor made a mistake and is unable or unwilling to fix the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly "light" but technical explanation of the problem may be found at https://scotthelme.co.uk/impending-doom-root-ca-expiring-legacy-clients/. Your question, though, indicates many will find even this a burden.

So I attempt to summarize this explanation below, using only "server certificate" and "root certificate" as necessary technical terms (although I assume the reader knows what type of computer or device they're dealing with).

- Every web server sends you a **server certificate** which traces back to a long-lived certificate called a **root certificate**. (There will be other certificates in between, but we'll ignore them for this discussion.) Taken together, these certificates allow your browser or device to verify the site is the one you are trying to reach, and not an impostor.
- The root certificate corresponding with the certificate sent from every site you visit is preloaded on the device or in the browser, rather than being sent to you from the server.
- If there is no valid root certificate for a site on your device, you won't be able to reach the site securely. Many sites are configured so that if you cannot reach the site securely, you won't be able to reach it at all.
- The problem is that some of these root certificates are about to expire and become invalid. When that happens, the server certificates which trace back to these root certificates also become invalid as far as your device is concerned, unless a new root certificate also corresponding with the server certificate is installed on your device.
- For general-purpose operating systems (OS, e.g. Windows, Linux, Mac) and the browsers that run on them, the OS or browser maker will automatically install new root certificates as they are created, so for the most part this will not be a problem as long as the OS and browser are kept up-to-date.
- Where this becomes a problem is on devices which are no longer updated by their makers. These include embedded systems such as a router or a "smart appliance" like a TV, as well as mobile devices (Android, iOS) and computers with outdated OS (e.g. Windows 7 and earlier). If the OS cannot be patched or upgraded to include the new root certificates, the only solution available at the moment is to replace the device.

Comment: Windows 7 users should be fine, no?  Chrome extended support into July 2021 and Firefox probably much longer.

Comment: @pcalkins, that's true for at least the first of these certificates to expire since there has been a replacement root certificate out there for longer than Windows 7 has been in end-of-service-life status. In the general case, however, the longer the browser/app/device goes without updates, the more likely some sites will break.

Comment: strangely enough one of my Windows 7 machines just ran a Windows Update that installed Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, I have recently encountered this issue where my CA's root expired. Some of the software in use was ready, some not so much.

It might be harder for a non-technical user to understand the nuances, so I'd try to avoid them:

You own a car dealership which has employed many people of the course of 10 or 20 years.

While you still run the company, you want to make sure that none of the employees still have a key to the business and its valuables (sports cars, electronic re-key stations, parts, etc.)

Failure to secure things would mean a loss of reputation, franchise rights, and sales. You would obviously carry higher insurance rates as well.

***You decide that it would be best to "re-key" the doors*** **so that you can prove not only to yourself, but also to the insurance company that a future break in wasn't caused from a previous employee.**

Maybe this is just plain paranoia, or just that [door lock technology got so much better in the 10 to 20 years of business](https://www.bowleylockcompany.com/). You figure it would be about $3,000 to go ahead with this, where a loss and increase of insurance rates would cost you twice as much.

After a few days of using the "re-key" solution, you find that an employee can't unlock a door they normally use. Turns out they were using a previous key from the previous company that was in the car lot before you setup shop.

Plus who knows, maybe one of your employees lent his keys to a friend to "test drive" one of the sports cars, and duplicated the key while he was at it? How would you know this ever happened unless the car wasn't in the lot anymore?

***The "re-key" of the doors allowed you to detect this issue, and resolve it quickly.***

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with the other answer that says that explaining the why and how to non-technical users isn't all that important.  "How" and "Why" answers are often not important for people to know.  Most of the time "Who" questions are more relevant.

Still, *some* people do benefit from understanding how and why, so it might be useful to provide them with some way to explain what's going on.

1. Encryption relies on trust and proof.  Inside each device is a copy of many trusted organizations credentials, each with a varying   expiration date.  These organizations are called "Certificate   Authorities", and the credential is called a "Root Certificate".  This is used to certify that "www.example.com" is actually "www.example.com"  The Root Certificate essentially says "Trust Certificate  Authority XYZ company until 1/1/2021", much like a passport.  The expiration dates are generally decades from when they were first created.
2. On the other end of internet, on a website or a similar service is a second certificate signed by the Certificate Authority that says "this is www.example.com".  When your computer, or  device connects to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), it compares the signature and expiration date inside its store of credentials with what [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) has sent. If the certificate isn't expired, and the signature matches, it allows the    communication.  If the signature doesn't match, or the certificate IS expired, it doesn't allow the communication.
3. The certificates inside the device eventually expire, and need to be replaced with newer ones.  The Certificate Authorities know this, and routinely create new credentials that expire further in the future. But those credentials need to be put on every computer or internet device, and sometimes that doesn't happen. Not replacing the certificates can happen for a variety of reasons.  For instance, the company who made who made the device doesn't want to spend money on maintaining them, it's too difficult to update them all, they're out of business, they just want you to buy a new device, or they just weren't tracking the expiration (often the most likely scenario).
4. Many times this problem can be delayed by getting a certificate for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) signed by a Certificate Authority with an expiration date further in the future.  That's only possible if the device has a Root Certificate that hasn't already expired.  This only delays the problem, since eventually all the old certificates in the device will expire.

So the underlying problem is one of maintenance.  If no-one is maintaining the software inside these devices, eventually they won't work, or at best they won't be able to use encryption to communicate on the internet.

This is often a difficult task since it's Yet Another Thing that has to be tracked and accounted for by what's already over-commited IT departments.

Answer (score -2):

I've found that non-technical users are best served with analogies. I am taking some heavy liberties and deliberately excluding complications that do not have anything to do with the core problem.

Imagine you're a low ranking noble in a magical medieval world, like The Witcher from Netflix. You get orders from the higher ranking ranking nobles above you and you need to give orders yourself to the land owners and village leaders below you. However, there's been problems with people intercepting orders and even altering them.

The magical advisers to the royal families of your world have come up with magical spells (aka root certificates) for their signet rings (domain certificates) that, when used to seal a letter, will add potent magic to these letters (aka encryption) so they can only be read after opening them using magical letter openers (aka computers), which will break enchantments they recognize as being made by the wizard. Note that it's the spell itself that does this, not the signet ring. If a noble above you gets a new signet ring because his old one broke, or because the noble got executed and a different noble took his place, your letter opener will still be able to break the enchantment on these letters. And your underlings below you will still be able to read your successor's letters with the same letter opener.

However, the problem is that the magical spell becomes easier to break by experienced mages over time and will eventually be so old that even an apprentice mage might break them, so the enchantment will need to be replaced at some point (expiration). However, there's a problem: the letter openers the nobles have are all attuned to the old spell, so they will all need to get their own letter opener enchants renewed to be able to read the new letters.

The good news is that the magical advisers already predicted this would happen, so they prepared new enchants for both signet rings and letter openers a couple of years before the old enchants would expire. The bad news is that some nobles never got their enchants renewed for whatever reason, so they won't be able to open these new letters, or even make new letters for their underlings. In order to continue reading messages created after the spell expired, these nobles will have to acquire new enchants for their letter openers.

Comment: I am experienced with encryption and a life-long fan of fantasy fiction, and this analogy is impossible to follow. You have a problem where you are trying to explain one arcane concept with another. You might as well just skip the magic and talk about encryption because you are still using "technical terms", it's just that you swapped technologies. To explain "without technical terms" means to relate to what someone already has general knowledge of. Are you aware that there are established analogies to explain public key encryption?

Comment: @schroeder You mean the padlock analogy? I forgot about that one. Everyone knows about padlocks though, and AFAIK there isn't really a padlock analogy equivalent to root certificates, so it would still be the same issue. However, if you can suggest something that can work in a padlock situation, I will update my answer using that analogy.

Comment: Padlock is one. There are others.